# Read QR Code from PDF files and Export data to excel using python

Tags: python, pdf, qr-code

I have been trying to read QR Code from PDF files from a folder using python and export the data to Excel.
The below code I have bene using for reading the PDF but i am not getting the output on it.

```
def read_qr_code(filename):
    """Read an image and read the QR code.

Args:
    filename (string): Path to file

Returns:
    qr (string): Value from QR code
"""

try:
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    detect = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
    value, points, straight_qrcode = detect.detectAndDecode(img)
    return value
except:
    return

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['filename', 'qr'])
files = glob.glob('data/*.jpg')

for file in files:

    qr = read_qr_code(file)
    row = {'filename': file, 'qr': qr}
    
    df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)

df.head()
```

Comment: @KJ Thanks for the Suggestion, But wherever i am looking for the solution i can only see Reading QR Code from Image but i need to directly Read it from PDF File